# Line break in Label Box

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I give line break in `label box` using C#?

Here is my code is there to show the values from database in a label box:

```
protected List<string> restwo;
lblKeyword.Text =  restwo[17];
```

Here I create a list for showing the data from database. `restwo` is an array variable and I am assigning to label box whatever is in the array list. In this array list, I am using this:

```
"t, applet, class, money, July, you, clue, collection, Java, add, add, add, club, dildos, class, class, applet, t, your, Java, Java, add, collection"
```

It will show a very lengthy label text. This will be a problem for my design. Here I want include a line break. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What about a ListBox ?

Comment: What's a `label box`? You mean a `Label`?

Comment: Also, the `Label` control does line breaks by default when the `Text` is too long.

Answer (score 2):

Use **"\r\n"** or **br** at appropriate places.
for example: In winforms for label

```
label1.text= "t, applet, class, money, July, you, clue, collection,"+"\r\n"+"Java, add, add, add, club, dildos, class, class, applet, t";
```

Comment: Or Environment.LineBreak

Comment: @MikeGoodwin, you mean `Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: actually this Label box value will change depends on the data from the database. i cant mention like this

Comment: how to use the Environment.NewLine in lblKeyword.Text =  restwo[17]; this statement